# Wchar_t to string Conversion

Tags: c++, string, wchar, readdirectorychangesw

I want to convert the **strFileNotifyInfo[1].FileName**(Wchar_t) to a string so that i can see the filepath. but i can't make it work.

Here is my code:

```
while(TRUE)
{
    if( ReadDirectoryChangesW( hDir, (LPVOID)&strFileNotifyInfo, sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo), FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE || FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION, &dwBytesReturned, NULL, NULL) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Reading Directory Change" << endl;
    }
    else
    {

        cout << ("File Modified: ") << strFileNotifyInfo[1].FileName << endl;
        cout << ("Loop: ") << nCounter++ << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it's a `wchar_t`. Did you mean `wchar_t*`?

Comment: try WideCharToMultiByte API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, it is a Wchar_t*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wcout` when working with wide character data.

```
std::wcout << L"File Modified: " << strFileNotifyInfo[1].FileName << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also keep in mind that [FileName is not null-terminated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
WCHAR* filename_w = strFileNotifyInfo[1].FileName;
DWORD filename_len = strFileNotifyInfo[1].FileNameLength;
std::string filename(filename_w, filename_w + filename_len);
std::cout << "File Modified: " << filename << std::endl;
```